# Javascript nested for array represent issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two array that intersect two element as you see below. Normally this function should write as A, B, Y but it represents all value lista.length * listb.length

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){     
        var lista = [];
        lista[0] = "A";
        lista[1] = "B";
        lista[2] = "Y";

        var listb = [];
        listb[0] = "A";
        listb[1] = "B";

        for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<listb.length; j++){
                if(listb[j] == lista[i]){
                    document.write(listb[j] + "<br/>");
                }else{
                    document.write(lista[i] + "<br/>");                 
                }               
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could print only the element of the outer loop

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var lista = ["A", "B", "Y"],
        listb = ["A", "B"];

    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        document.write(lista[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < listb.length; j++) {
            if (listb[j] == lista[i]) {
                document.write(" common");
                break;
            }
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until the end of the inner loop to know whether you found a match or not, not print `lista[i]` for every non-matching element.

```
    for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<listb.length; j++){
            var found = false;
            if(listb[j] == lista[i]){
                document.write(listb[j] + "<br/>");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!found){
                document.write(lista[i] + "<br/>");                              
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
 <script>
        window.onload = function(){     
          var lista = [];
          lista[0] = "A";
          lista[1] = "B";
          lista[2] = "Y";
    
          var listb = [];
          listb[0] = "A";
          listb[1] = "B";
    
          for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<listb.length; j++){
              if(lista[i] == listb[j]){
                 document.write(listb[j] + "<br/>");
                break
              }else{
                 document.write(lista[i] + "<br/>");                 
                break
              }               
            }
          }
        }

  </script>
```